# Custom parameter for sorting passed into URL using ORDER BY

Tags: java, sql, jpql

I would like to state first that I know there is a sorting function already, and it can be called using this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/person?sort=name,ASC
```

However, as I'm relying on multiple domains I am unable to use this sort type at the moment. From that I have decided to make a custom sorting parameter so something like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/person?ordering=name
```

I then decided to look into my repository to create a custom JPQL that could be used to possible sort my values when calling the URL above:

REPO METHOD:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM DePerson p, DeClass c, DeSchool s" +
    "WHERE p.personId = c.id " +
    "AND p.schoolId = s.id " +
    "ORDER BY :ordering")
Page<DeSiteUser> orderingAll(@Param("ordering") String ordering, Pageable pageable);
```

SERVICE METHOD:

```
    Page<DePerson> newPage = repository.orderingAll(ordering, pageable);

    List<DePerson> personList = newPage.getContent();
    for (DePerson person: personList ) {
        result.add(convertDTO(person));
    }

    return new PageImpl<>(result, pageable, page.getTotalElements());
```

From this I have then called it and now have been given this error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Two questions I would like ask. 1. Is this the right track to produce a custom sorting parameter using ORDER BY. 2. Why am I getting the error. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This line looks wrong:

```
AND su.schoolId = s.id
```

There is no 'su' in your request.  Did you mean c instead of su?

Comment: Sorry, that is one me. Didn't copy it right. It should be P, not su. Fixing now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do it like below. There is no need to define a method in the repository.

```
Pageable pageable =  PageRequest.of(0, limit, Sort.by("fieldName"));

Page<DePerson> newPage = repository.findAll(pageable);
```

**References**

1. You can check the last example on this [article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting)
2. Also [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/PageRequest.html#of-int-int-org.springframework.data.domain.Sort-) is the official documentation

**Furthermore** if you want to retrieve class and school then you can have a `ManyToOne` or `OneToOne` relationship inside your DePerson class and can get all that loaded automatically in your DePerson object, no need to define those classes separately in the Query and in where class. By the it is `INNER Join` that you will need to use for combining records from multiple tables/entities

**Otherwise** there is another concept of DTO class projections like [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/dto-projections/)

In the context of this article you can add the order by as below

```
// Execute query
Order orderByBookTitle = cb.asc(root.get(Book_.title));
// or
Order orderByAuthorFirstName = cb.asc(author.get(Author_.firstName));
cq.orderBy(orderByDeptTitle, orderByAuthorFirstName);
TypedQuery<BookWithAuthorNames> q = em.createQuery(cq);
q.setParameter(paramTitle, "%Hibernate Tips%");
List<BookWithAuthorNames> books = q.getResultList();
```

Comment: Thank you but said stated I am unable to use the sort by method, that is why I'm looking for the order by method.

Comment: What is your field name in the DePerson class that you want to use for sorting?

Comment: Do you want to retrieve data from three entities into a single object?

Comment: Hello! Yes I think we are along the same lines. You see I'm looking to to access the name from the other doman classes as well, that is why I thought about using ORDER BY in the query. When using sort by, I can only access the values from DePerson but I want to access the info from others, any advce?

Comment: Please see the last suggestion in my answer.

Comment: I do have a PersonDTO which contains all the info I need, I saw your "Otherwise" section there. Would you have any idea how I could do the sorting method on a DTO object?

Comment: Please check snippet I have added in the answer